# Making addition and multiplication tables in php.

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I need help creating tables in php. Here is the code that I have right now. I have the correct html code I just need help with my php code.

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" >
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Number of Rows:</td><td><input type="text" name="rows" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Number of Columns:</td><td><select name="columns">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="16">16</option>

</select>
</td></tr>
```

Operation:Multiplication
    Addition

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        //check to see if num of rows is numeric
    if ( isset($_POST["rows"]) && is_numeric($_POST["rows"])){
            //check to see if rows is a positive number
            if($_POST["rows"] > 0){
                    //if the multiplication button is checked do this
                    if(isset($_POST) && $_POST["operation"] == "multiplication"){
                            //start the table and post what type of table it is
                            echo 'This is a '. $_POST["rows"] . ' x ' . $_POST["columns"]    .'multiplication table';
                            echo "<table border=1";
                            echo'<tr>'; 
                    //post the first row
                    for($b = 0; $b <= $_POST["columns"];$b++){
                            echo '<th>'.$b.'</th>';}
                            echo '</tr>';
                    //nested for loops to finish the table
                    for($r = 1; $r <= $_POST["rows"]; $r++){

                            echo'<tr><th>'.$r.'</th>';

                            for($c = 1; $c <= $_POST["columns"]; $c++){
                                    echo '<td>' .$c*$r. '</td>';
```

Comment: Where do you actually run the query?

Comment: I thought the isset statment would run the query? I guess not lol Ill look into that, thanks

Comment: No, `isset()` returns a boolean value if the `execute` key of the `$_POST` super-global is set. You need to actually run the query, and then fetch the results.

Comment: @BenM Does this look any better? I am still confused about how to print out the information

Comment: Did you exchange the question for completely different one?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the query using a function like `mysqli::query($query);`. This function returns some content which you can then fetch/display with some other functions. But remember to connect to the database first and that stuff...

I'd recommend you to read some guides about mysqli first ;) Then it's quite self-explanating.

Comment: Thanks. already on it. I will post what I find and hopefully someone can confirm that what I am doing is correct

Comment: No problem :) Connecting to a database & fetching data is the easiest and most redundant part. Writing a query syntax & optimizing it is the hardest part (which you have apparently done already)

Comment: I can understand the logic of my programs quite well, I just struggle with how to write what I want to do sometimes.

Comment: Does my updated code look any better? I am still confused on how to print out the information, especially since the information changes with both queries